More information needed on summarize_glm_count()
Chelsea Dickens and I are trying to understand where the outputs under "Unadjusted exacerbation rate (per year)" and "Adjusted (QP) exacerbation rate (per year)" from the example in Summarize Poisson negative binomial regression are calculated by summarize_glm_count() and associated functions (e.g., s_glm_count()).
Which package(s)/functions is this built on, and how are these calculations done?
Is it possible to add details to the function documentation to detail this or to add a reference that contains details for the calculations?
Thank you!

summarize_glm_count is the statistical, user-facing function s_glm_count. If you check the source code, you will see that it is based on h_glm_count, a helper function that directs to different distribution-adjusted calculations. If you take a look at h_glm_poisson, for example, you will see that it is a stats:glm with Poisson distr family from which estimated marginal means are calculated with emmeans::emmeans(). In h_glm_poisson, you also see where the covariates, wights, offset, and arm are used.
I understand it needs to be clarified from a user perspective. I am adding details to the function documentation.
The unadjusted label for the first example is wrong imo as it uses Poisson's default distribution.

Thank you for the reply and for adding details to the function documentation - that is helpful!
